# Guardar tarjetas en aplicaciones multi clientes con MercadoPago

Tags: mercadopago

estoy generando una app de mercadopago, la cual tiene multiples clientes, en esta app necesito poder guardar las tarjetas de los usuarios para que puedan volver a usarla mas adelante.

la pregunta es, el usuario, lo genero con el access_token de la app? y despues solo emito la compra con el token del cliente?

1. cliente: tienda que me da accesso a poder cobrar con su mercadopago
2. usuario: la persona que entra a mi sitio a poder comprar

**EDIT**

En nuestro sitio tenemos muchos productos de muchas tiendas, por ende el usuario no tiene un carro de compras como tal, entra a un producto y compra ese producto, pero necesito que los usuarios puedan guardar sus tarjetas una sola vez, y que esa tarjeta pueda ser usada en las multiples tiendas que tenemos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que quieres hacer en mercado pago se llama *"customer and cards"* esta característica te permite guardar un usuario de tu aplicación usando el access_token desde el endpoint

[api.mercadopago.com/customers](http://api.mercadopago.com/customers)

Una vez hayas creado un usuario puedes guardar sus tarjetas de crédito asociadas para disponer de la funcionalidad de "billetera", por seguridad se puede consultar posteriormente únicamente un card_token que es un identificador de la tarjeta guardada para utilizarlo en la aplicación posteriormente para realizar un pago, proceso para el cual sera necesario solicitar el cvv de la tarjeta como mecanismo de seguridad para procesar un pago con una tarjeta guardada.

Referencia:

https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/api-docs/custom-checkout/customers-cards/
https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/customers-and-cards/